# django-messages messages_inbox_count template tag not working as expected

Tags: django, django-templates

I am new to django and trying to use django-messages to add inbox/compose/outbox/trash functionality for my site users. From the doc i have completed the following steps:

1. pip install django-messages
2. added `'messages',` to `INSTALLED_APPS`
3. added django-messages `'messages.context_processors.inbox',` context processor to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

Finally i am trying to use `messages_inbox_count` tag inside one of my template as follows:

```
<a href="/messages/inbox/">Inbox ({{ messages_inbox_count }})</a>
```

However, as expected this doesn't show up any inbox count on the page.
Also, using django-debug-toolbar i am able to view that their is indeed a variable names messages_inbox_count. Below is a snipped from *Templates Sidebar* of django-debug-toolbar:

```
Context processors
django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth
▶ Toggle Context
social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_name_backends
▶ Toggle Context
messages.context_processors.inbox
▼ Toggle Context
{'messages_inbox_count': 1}
django.core.context_processors.csrf
▶ Toggle Context
social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_backends
▶ Toggle Context
```

What am i really doing wrong here? Seems like a stupid thing to fix but with no luck at my end :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a RequestContext-Instance to render the Template where the value does not appear, or just a Context?

(For example: if you use render_to_response, you need to make sure to include a `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` argument.)

Comment: that was it... turned out my lack of knowledge with django did me here... at rest of the places i end up using `context_instance`, for my django-messages test template i wasn't doing this. BTW I am really loving django :)